# Change image ImageView with back button

Tags: swift

I'm new on coding in Swift. My first project contains a set of images shown with an next button. What i need is a back button so when you are on image 3 you go back to image 2 etc. Can anybody help me? Here is the code that works fine with a next button.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!

    var imageList: [String] = [“Image1.png”, ”Image2.png”, ”Image3.png”]
    var nameList: [String] = [“Text1”, ”Text2”, ”Text3”]

    let maxImgs = 3
    var imgIndex: NSInteger = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: ”Image1”) !)

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: ”Image1”)
        labelText.text = nameList[0]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    @IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if imgIndex > maxImgs {
            imgIndex = 0
        }
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageList[imgIndex])
        labelText.text = nameList[imgIndex]
        imgIndex += 1

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this function inside your `viewController`

```
@IBAction func previousButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if imgIndex < 0 {
        imgIndex = maxImgs
    }
    imageView.image = UIImage(named:imageList[imgIndex])
    labelText.text = nameList[imgIndex]
    imgInde-=1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respons

Comment: When i add the function i get this:libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Happy to hear. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
let images:[UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "Image1.png"),UIImage(named: "Image2.png"),UIImage(named: "Image3.png")]
var index:Int = 0
```

on Forward button:

```
if(index < images.count){
    index = index + 1
    imageView.image = images[index]
}
```

on Back button:

```
if(index >= 0){
    index = index - 1
    imageView.image = images[index]
}
```

And to stop at last image:

disable the button when `index = 0` or `index = images.count`

Or you can just use your own code like this:

```
@IBAction func previousButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if imgIndex == 0 {
        imgIndex = maxImgs
    }
    imgIndex -= 1
    imageView.image = UIImage(named:imageList[imgIndex])
    labelText.text = nameList[imgIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the same as your `nextButton` function....just the other way around :)

```
@IBAction func previousButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if imgIndex == 0 {
        imgIndex = maxImgs
    }
    imgIndex -= 1
    imageView.image = UIImage(named:imageList[imgIndex])
    labelText.text = nameList[imgIndex]
}
```

First you make sure that you won't "go over the edge" by checking that your index isn't 0. If it is, you set it to `maxImgs` (which is 3)

Then you decrement the `imgIndex` value by one and can then use that to get your previous image from the various arrays.

Hope that helps you.